Does a large rock in a Viking boat burial symbolize a vulva?
A 9th Century gravesite from Fitjar, Norway is making the news today because it included some women with jewellery, and because the mast of a boat is "symbolized" with a rock.

... When the archaeologists turned it over, they saw that it resembled a ‘vulva stone’ – the stone looked like female genitalia.  “That the stone resembles a woman is no coincidence. It's so obvious,” says Diinhoff.

The rock is a big, flattish rock with a very shallow, wide groove in it.
I didn't see a link to an academic publication.
I'm skeptical because I didn't quickly find other references to such stones on longboats, but mostly because it seems so obviously something else!
Modern recreational fishermen tend to grab any old thing you can tie a rope around as an anchor - coffee cans full of concrete, small stumps, or irregular stones - and the base of the mast seems like the only sensible place to store an anchor on any boat that could raise sail.  The scallop at one edge would be as useful as the groove (I doubt the rope aligned exactly with the groove).
Did this rock symbolize a vulva?

Why would they put an anchor stone in something that wasn't a boat? It is a grave with stones arranged in the shape of a boat, not an actual boat.

If they had wanted it to resemble a vulva, wouldn't they have chosen or carved a rock that resembled it rather better than this one?

Another Viking burial site at Gammel Lejre in Denmark also has stone ship-shaped burial places, some of which have stones within them. Also this paper about the symbolic use of whetstones says they were used for ritual purposes. Perhaps this stone was worn by constant use in the trade of the deceased. Note that the groove does not seem to be aligned with the burial ship in the aerial photos.
